# Margin-top doesn't get applied (not working)

Tags: html, css, alignment

This question is for [this website](http://freshbeer.lv/final/index.html)

Everything is good but for some reason my `.content` div, which is given a css rule 
 `margin-top: 50px;` doesn't seem to have that margin working on it. I gave bright yellow background colour to the div that has problem so you can see it.

Here is **css** code of elements that might cause the issue. (Not sure it could be other elements as well.)

```
header {
    background-color: #1d130e;
    background-image: url("../img/header_bg.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border-top: 1px solid #0d0907;
    border-bottom: 1px soid #0d0907;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px -1px #181513;
}

.content {
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #eef496;
}
```

And **HTML** of the page:

```
<body>
        <!-- Header -->
        <header>
            ...
        </header>
        <!-- Header [END] -->

        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="content">
            <!-- Slideshow -->
            ...
            <!-- Slideshow [END] -->
        </div>
        <!-- Content [END] -->

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer></footer>
        <!-- Footer [END] -->
    </body>
```

Comment: When you are already using the `<header>` and `<footer>` tags, you should also use `<section class="content">` instead of `<div class="content">`. This is semantically more appropriate (but doesn't refer to your question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the line `margin: 0 auto;` you're overriding the margin-top property.
Try out this:

```
.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 1000px;
    background: #eef496;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, it's happening to forget something don't worry :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.content {

    width: 1000px;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
    background: #eef496;
}
```

Or you can simply

```
margin: 50px auto 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see a slides div that is inside the content div. I gave a margin-top to the slides div and it applied that seems to be working

```
<div id="slides"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome I get the following CSS lines on `.content`:

```
.content {
   margin-top: 50px; /* margin-top is defined */
   width: 1000px;
   margin: 0 auto; /* all the margins are overridden, including margin-top */
   background: #EEF496;
   display: block;
}
```

The line in the third line makes sure that the first line is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, what you want to do but the page seems about right. Have you cleared your browser cache?

If you don't want overlapping margins at all, try

```
overflow: hidden;
```

on the element with the margin and the one touching it.